# Posible origen de la frase "buen hombre"

Tags: significado, modismos

Según tengo entendido antes se le decía despectivamente a la gente "buen hombre", como diciendo "pobre diablo", o "pobre tipo".

Por ejemplo, En el libro del Quijote, cuando al hidalgo se le dice así, "buen hombre", éste se enoja y contesta groseramente a un cuadrillero.

**¿Cómo es que algo como "buen hombre", era despectivo?**

---

### Lo que el libro dice es:

**Buen hombre:** era fórmula de tratamiento aplicada a los inferiores, con
valor casi despectivo, equivalente a "pobre hombre" de donde la
irritación de don Quijote (vid. I-iv, n. 40;y n. 13).

---

**Fragmento extraído del Don quijote de la Mancha, I-XVII:**

> Llegó el cuadrillero, y, como los halló hablando en tan sosegada
>   conversación, quedó suspenso. Bien es verdad que aún don Quijote se
>   estaba boca arriba, sin poderse menear, de puro molido y emplastado.
>   Llegóse a él el cuadrillero y díjole:
>
> - Pues¿Cómo va, buen hombre?
> - Hablara yo más bien criado -respondió don Quijote-, si fuera que vos. ¿Úsase en tierra hablar desa suerte a los caballeros andantes,
>     majadero?
>
> El cuadrillero que se vio tratar tan mal de un hombre de tan mal
>   parecer, no lo pudo sufrir, y, alzando el candil con todo su aceite,
>   dio a don quijote con él en la cabeza, de suerte que le dejó muy bien
>   descalabrado; y, como todo quedó ascuras, salióse luego; y Sancho
>   Panza dijo:
>
> - Sin duda, señor que éste es el moro encantado, y debe de guardar el tesoro para otros, y para nosotros sólo guarda las puñadas y los
>     candilazos.

Comment: Busqué y encontré distintos fragmentos. ¿Podrías copiar un trozo del fragmento de El Quijote donde dice tal cosa? Lo mismo es pura ironía -o malentendido, tan frecuentes en ese libro-.

Comment: @fedorqui de acuerdo. No salen muchos ejemplos en Google Books de antes de 1700, pero sin duda alguna, en todos los ejemplos que he visto, tiene connotación buena.

Comment: Por cierto, el *Quijote* no pertenece al período medieval, sino aurisecular.

Comment: En el libro del quijote que poseo, dice al pie del libro, varias explicaciónes de lo que en la época de Servantes significaban ciertas frases. Voy a buscar donde lo explica, y les daré más datos.

Comment: En este caso, es más probable que buen hombre habría sido un insulto a alguien a que se precisase dirigirse con más reverencia. Por ejemplo, un caballero. Es parecido a llamar señor al que se haya doctorado hoy en día: *señor* es tratamiento de respeto, siempre que la persona no merezca tratamiento superior, y en tal caso, sería despectivo.

Comment: Gracias, pero lo que buscaba era un posible origen, de porque fue un insulto llamar buen hombre a un tipo.

Sí solo es por no dar los honores y nombrarlo...

Comment: Creo que el comentario de guifa es la respuesta correcta. "Buen hombre" no es que sea negativo, es que pertenece al pueblo llano. Y Don Quijote se consideraba un caballero andante, por lo cual lo consideraba despectivo. Es como si al Rey de España lo saludas con un "Hey, que pasa colega". Colega no es despectivo, de hecho implica camaradería, pero se podría considerar un insulto si se utiliza con la realeza

Comment: A mí también me sorprende, lo cual hace la pregunta más interesante. La frase-explicación que @Lobo-Eze ha extraído del libro de Cervantes explica con claridad que 1) no es una mala interpretación nuestra de un párrafo, y 2) alguien (que ha publicado el libro de Cervantes en nuestros tiempos, algo docto en el tema será) ha incluido la aclaración sobre este significado 'despectivo' de "buen hombre", luego seguro que se ha encontrado con este uso en numerosas ocasiones y probablemente con distintos orígenes (autores). Mi parecer es que esta pregunta merece ser respondida :)

Comment: No has oido hablar del sarcasmo?  Se me hace otro ejemplo del genio de cervantes.

Answer (score 8):

La palabra española **bonhomía** es un galicismo que significa `afabilidad, sencillez, bondad y honradez en el carácter y en el comportamiento` según la RAE. Proviene del francés *bonhomie*, con el mismo significado, que a su vez proviene de **bon homme** que significa literalmente **buen hombre**, pero que ha cargado distintos sentidos y valores en la historia lingüística de Francia.

Con seguridad Don Quijote confundió el sentido español de *buen hombre* con el sentido peyorativo que tenía la palabra *bonhomme* en Francia de la época. Tal vez en España del Siglo de Oro *buen hombre* también tenía un valor negativo o ambivalente, pero al parecer no.

Como sea, Don Quijote tenía la mente puesta en el medioevo. El uso de *bonhomme* con sentido peyorativo en Francia aparece por primera vez en las crónicas de Jean Froissart, uno de los responsables del renacimiento caballeresco de fines de la Edad Media, en el cual estaba imbuido con bastante atraso Don Quijote.

Guillaume Cale, el líder de una famosa [revuelta campesina en 1358](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande_Jacquerie), es conocido en la crónica de Froissart como **Jacques Bonhomme**. Aquí *Bonhomme* es un epíteto de nobleza, similar a *señor*, mientras que *Jacques* hace alusión a la chaqueta (*jaque*) que usaban los campesinos. Froissart, que era partidario de la nobleza, estaba diciendo tanto *Juan Buen Hombre* como *Señorito de Chaqueta*.

Con este apodo irónico y despectivo los nobles llamaban a sus siervos hasta la época de la Revolución Francesa, en que, obviamente, el valor se invirtió. Desde entonces *bonhomme* alude al hombre sencillo y bondadoso por naturaleza.

Don Quijote entendió que le estaban diciendo "campesino".

Comment: Exquisita respuesta. Muchisimas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

La RAE indica la expresión "buen hombre" como "expresión rural", esto es, empleada más comúnmente en el ámbito rural. Incluso hoy su empleo indica una cierta superioridad del hablante respecto al interpelado, por lo que es francamente desaconsejable. Tan solo recuerdo una expresión común que la emplee actualmente, que es "cálmese buen hombre".

Comment: Algo lateralmente relacionado: la palabra "hombrecito". Recuerdo la impresión que en una ocasión me produjo que alguien presentara una persona ante mi padre —recomendándolo como buen trabajador— con en supuesto elogio diciendo _"este hombrecito, es un buen ... [artesano/pintor/o algo parecido]"_

Comment: El caso es más directamente derogatorio (por el diminutivo), pero ilustra acaso la ofensa hecha de manera descuidada y posiblemente inconsciente, por la cortedad del rango con el que se refiere a alguien , pudiendo sonar insultante o irrespetuoso

Answer (score 0):

En la Edad Media un buen hombre era como se designada a un catarro y la forma de identificarlo, un buen hombre era  un hereje catarro, desde entonces se veía mal ser designado así. Dado el fin de los catarros nadie quería que se le llamase así... Se vincula a eso y al carácter de los cataros

Comment: CATARO, este corrector juega malas pasadas

Comment: Siempre puedes hacer un edit sobre tu propio post. Deberías corregirlo para clarificar lo que explicas, además de poner alguna referencia que respalde el contenido del post.